# Running a docker container on the host from a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize 2 dotnet console application that one depends on the other.
When I run the 1st container I need it to run another container on the host, insert a parameter to it's stdin and wait for it to end the job and exit.
What will be the best solution to achieve this?

Running a container inside a container seems to me like a bad solution,
I've also thought about managing another process with a webserver (nginx or something) on the host that get the request as http request and execute a docker run command in the host but I'm sure there is a better solution for this (in this way the webserver will just run on the host and not inside a container).

There is also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63576841/16086911) but it seems to have major security issues.

I've tried also using the Docker.DotNet library but it does not help with my problem.
any ideas for the best solution?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I will be using docker compose but the problem is that the 2nd container is not running and listening at all time, similar to the Hello-World container it's called, performs it's job and exits.

**EDIT2: FIX**

I've implemented redis as a message broker to communicate between the different services, while it changed the requirement a little (containers will always run and listen to redis) it helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: If you need to coordinate multiple containers would docker-comoose work for your purposes?

Comment: yes, I will be using docker compose, the problem is that the container is not running and listening all the time, it should run only when it's called and after performing it's job it should exit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand correctly what you need to do, but if you simply need to start two containers in parallel the simplest way I can think of is [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Another way is with a python or bash/bat script that launches the containers independently (in python you can either use the [Docker API](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or do it manually with the subprocess module). This allows you to perform other things (like writing on the *stdin* of one container, as you stated).

Comment: First solution would be possible if the 2nd container was always running, but it should run only on demand. The second solution means that the python script should be running on the host and not inside a container and it's a point of failure

Comment: I did not understand you needed to bring the container up on demand. In this case you can run the script on the shot through ssh (after setting up a network). Not sure is this is what you wanted though.

Comment: Solved this issue with redis as message broker, edited my original question. Thank you for your help.